# login authentication in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I want to use the authenticaton for custom user model in django. i just created the authentication for custom user model. but it's not validating the username and password. anyone help for that where i was mistaken the code.

Here it is my views.py file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def loginpage(request):
 if request.method =='POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('profile')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Comment: First of all, what is `post`? and why you're mixing post and user together? Please see here for usage of [authenticate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate)

Comment: i just modified my code. could you please suggest the best way for that authentication.

Comment: What do you have `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` set to? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authenticate logic is wrong. Because you gave queryset to authenticate function.You can provide username and password directly. There is a sample for authenticate based on [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users)

And change your `request.POST.['username']` with `request.POST.get("username")`,
`request.POST.['password']` with `request.POST.get("password")`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
if user is not None:
    # User exist
else:
    # No user founded with this username and password
```

Comment: i just added what you are mentioned above your. but it's not working. can you see my modified code.

Comment: please remove `request` parameter from `authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)`

Comment: can you check whether  username and password are empty?And can you try to get username and password with `request.POST.get("username")` and `request.POST.get("password")`